# Tumblr: Reblog posts without details

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

Sometimes, when I reblog a post, it appears like this (please see the left picture in grey box with original blog name above).

[image]

In order to have the post shown as we have in the right side, I've tried to apply [this](https://itstillworks.com/13332348/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-the-playlist-in-winamp) workaround but it doesn't work.

Tumblr dashboard "Customize" / "Edit HTML" and pasted the following code into the editor, before the `{/block:Posts}` tag:

```
<div class="sources"> {block:ContentSource} Source: <a href="{SourceURL}">{SourceTitle} </a> {/block:ContentSource} {block:RebloggedFrom} Via: <a href="{ReblogParentURL}">{ReblogParentName}</a> {/block:RebloggedFrom}</div>
```

In Advanced tab, Custom CSS section: `.sources { filter:alpha(opacity=0); opacity:0; }`
No results. Then I've tried this one pasted in HTML code:

```
{block:ContentSource}
    <a class="post_source" href="{SourceURL}" title="Source: {SourceTitle}" target="_blank"> Source </a>
{/block:ContentSource}
```

In Advanced tab, Custom CSS section: `.post_source { display: none }`
Also, no results.

The `html` source code of the blog ( https://beehoowoo.tumblr.com/ ) it's the following:

```
    <!--
 
Classic Theme brought to you by Atlas Designs
https://atlasdesigns.co/

Do not remove credits unless given permission to do so.
 
Updted July 2013 -
- new post formatting
- like/reblog buttons
- formatted text posts
- minor design tweaks
 
-->
 
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand|Raleway|PT Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 
{block:IndexPage}

<!----- SCROLL TOP/HOME/BOTTOM A1  ---->
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         $(function () {
             $('#scrlBotm').click(function () {
                 $('html, body').animate({
                     scrollTop: $(document).height()
                 },
                 1500);
                 return false;
             });

             $('#scrlTop').click(function () {
                 $('html, body').animate({
                     scrollTop: '0px'
                 },
                 1500);
                 return false;
             });
         });
    </script>    
 
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/iBElrgjim/jquerymasonry.js"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/Qyblrgjfn/jqueryinfintescroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
var $content = $('#content');
$content.masonry({itemSelector: '.entry'}),
$content.infinitescroll({
navSelector : 'div#pagination',
nextSelector : 'div#pagination a#nextPage',
itemSelector : '.entry',
loading: {
finishedMsg: '',
img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/dbek3sy/pX1lrx8xv/ajax-loader.gif'
},
bufferPx : 600,
debug : false,
},
// call masonry as a callback.
function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements );
$newElems.hide();
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$content.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true, function(){$newElems.fadeIn(300);} );});});});</script>
{/block:IndexPage}
 
<meta name="color:background" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="color:text" content="#000000" />
<meta name="color:title" content="#000000" />
<meta name="color:link" content="#828282" />
<meta name="color:link hover" content="#eee" />
<meta name="color:scrollbar" content="#cccccc" />
<meta name="color:post background" content="#f0f0f0">

<meta name="if:uppercase nav links" content="1">
<meta name="if:show captions" content="0">
<meta name="if:raleway font" content="0">
<meta name="if:quicksand font" content="0">
<meta name="if:pt sans font" content="1">
<meta name="if:post animation" content="0">
<meta name="if:banner" content="0">
 
<meta name="text:home" content="home">
<meta name="text:archive" content="archive">
 
<meta name="image:background" content="" />
<meta name="image:banner" content="">
 
<style type="text/css">
 
 
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 7px; height: 0px; background:{color:background};}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: {color:scrollbar}; border-radius:10px;}
 
iframe#tumblr_controls {position:fixed; z-index:9999999999; top: 3px; margin: 0 0 0 0; right:4px; -webkit-filter: invert(100%);}
 
body {
background-color: {color:background};
background-image:url({image:Background});
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: repeat;
font-size:12px;
font-family:helvetica neue; 
 
{block:ifptsansfont}
font-family: pt sans;
{/block:ifptsansfont}
 
{block:ifralewayfont}
font-family: raleway;
{/block:ifralewayfont}
 
{block:ifquicksandfont}
font-family: quicksand;
{/block:ifquicksandfont}
 
line-height:14px;
text-transform:none;
color: {color:text};
}
 
#sidebar{
position:fixed;
top:150px;
width:200px;
left:15px;
text-align:center;}

.blogtitle{
font-size:16px;
color: {color:title};
}

.description{
font-size:13px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:15px;
}
 
#nav a{
font-size:12px;
line-height:14px;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-transform:lowercase;
{block:ifuppercasenavlinks}
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:12px;
{/block:ifuppercasenavlinks}
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
 
.answer{
margin-top: 228px;
width:90%;
padding-top: 1%;
padding-right: 2%;
padding-bottom: 1%;
padding-left: 2%;
background:{color:post background};
}
.answer img {
max-width:250px;
height:auto;
{block:permalinkpage}
width:auto;
height:auto;
{/block:permalinkpage}
}
 
a {
text-decoration:none;
color:{color:link};
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
 
a:link, a:active, a:visited{
color: {color:link};
}
 
a:hover{
color: {color:link hover};
}
 
div#content {
width: 1064px;
margin-left:220px;
margin-top:20px;
float:left;
position: absolute;
}
 
.entry{
padding:0.60%;
float:left;
height:auto;
background-color: #trans;
{block:IndexPage}
width:45%;
overflow:hidden;
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:650px;
height:auto;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
 
{block:ifpostanimation}
.entry:hover{
transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
{/block:ifpostanimation}
 
.title{
font-size:17px;
line-height:17px;
font-weight:600;
color: {color:title};
}
 
blockquote{
padding:0px 0px 0px 3px;
margin:0px 0px 0px 2px;
border-left: 2px solid #ddd;
}
 
.like_and_reblog_buttons {
position:absolute;
top:1%;
left:1%;
margin-top:25px;
margin-left:-15px;
list-style: none;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.entry:hover .like_and_reblog_buttons{
top:0px;    
opacity:1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
 
.like_and_reblog_buttons li {
float: left;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
border-radius:100%;
padding:10px;
height:18px;
width:18px;
}
 
.like_and_reblog_buttons li:first-child {
margin-right:8px;
}
 
.play{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-24px;
top:50%;
margin-top:-42px;
border:10px solid white;  
height:27px;
width:27px;
border-radius:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
 
.notess{
position:absolute;    
left:520px;
top:14px;    
height:500px;
width:450px;
overflow:scroll;
padding:10px;
background-color:{color:post background};
}
ol.notes {
list-style-type: none;
margin-top:20px;
padding:0px;
line-height:40px;
font-size:13px;
}
.notess img{
border-radius:100%;
}
 
.textbuttons ul{
list-style:none;
position:relative;
}
.textbuttons li {
list-style:None;    
float: right;
}
.textbuttons li:first-child {
margin-left:12px;
}
 
.textnote{
position:absolute;
left:6%;
bottom:15px;
font-weight:700;
font-size:12px;
}
.textnote a{
font-size:11px;    
color:gray;
}
 
.caption{
width:90%;
padding:5%;
background:#f7f7f7;
margin-top:-3px;
}
 
.chat li {
list-style-type:none;
margin-left:-40px;
padding:5px;
border-bottom:2px solid #dddddd;
}
.label{
font-weight:700;
font-size:11px;
}

html, body {overflow-x: hidden; }

{CustomCSS}
</style>
 
<title>{title}</title>
 
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="{RSS}" />
 
</head>


 
<body>



<div id="sidebar">
{block:ifnotbanner}
<a href="/"><span class="blogtitle">{Title}</span></a>
{/block:ifnotbanner}
{block:ifbanner}
<img src="https://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_d7e79ad5642b_128.png" alt="" width=96px style="border: none;"></a>
{/block:ifbanner}
<div class="description">{Description}</div>
<div id="nav">
<a href="/">{text:home}</a> <br>
<a href="/archive">{text:archive}</a> <br>
{block:HasPages}{block:Pages}<a href="{URL}">{Label}</a> <br>{/block:Pages}{/block:HasPages}
</div>
</div>
 
<div id="content">

{block:Posts}
 
<div class="entry">
 
{block:Text}
<div class="answer">{block:Title}<span class="title">{Title}</span>{/block:Title}{Body}
{block:IndexPage}<div class="textnote"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountwithLabel}</a></div>
<ul class="textbuttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
<li>{LikeButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
</ul><br>
{/block:IndexPage}
</div>
{/block:Text}
 
{block:Link}
<div class="answer"><a href="{URL}"><span class="title">{Name}</span></a>
{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
{block:IndexPage}<div class="textnote"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountwithLabel}</a></div>
<ul class="textbuttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
<li>{LikeButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
</ul><br>
{/block:IndexPage}
</div>
{block:Link}
 
{block:Photo}{block:HighRes}{/block:HighRes} 
{block:IndexPage}
<ul class="like_and_reblog_buttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="white" size=17}</li>
<li>{LikeButton color="white" size=17}</li>
</ul>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:IndexPage}{LinkOpenTag}<div class="photo"><a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width=100% style="border: none;" /></a></div>{LinkCloseTag}
{block:ifshowcaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:ifshowcaptions}
{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width=500px style="border: none;" />{LinkCloseTag}{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photo}
 
{block:Photoset}
<center>
{block:IndexPage}{Photoset-250}{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}{Photoset-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}
</center>
{block:IndexPage}<div class="textnote"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountwithLabel}</a></div>
<ul class="textbuttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
<li>{LikeButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
</ul><br>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Photoset}
 
{block:Quote}
<div class="answer"><div class="title">{Quote}</div>- {Source}
{block:IndexPage}<div class="textnote"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountwithLabel}</a></div>
<ul class="textbuttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
<li>{LikeButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
</ul><br>
{/block:IndexPage}
</div>
{/block:Quote}
 
{block:Chat}
<div class="answer">
<div style="margin-left:3px;">
{block:Title}<span class="title">{Title}</span>{/block:Title}
<ul class="chat">
{block:Lines}
<li class="user_{UserNumber}">
{block:Label}
<span class="label">{Label}</span>
{/block:Label}
{Line}
</li>
{/block:Lines}
</ul>
</div>
{block:IndexPage}<div class="textnote"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountwithLabel}</a></div>
<ul class="textbuttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
<li>{LikeButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
</ul><br>
{/block:IndexPage}
</div>
{/block:Chat}
 
{block:Audio}
{block:AlbumArt}
<center><a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{AlbumArtURL}" width="100%"></a></center>
{/block:AlbumArt}
<div class="play">{AudioPlayerWhite}</div>
{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
<ul class="like_and_reblog_buttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="white" size=17}</li>
<li>{LikeButton color="white" size=17}</li>
</ul>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:Audio}
 
{block:Answer}
<div class="answer"><div style="font-size:11px;line-height:11px;font-style:italic;color:{color:links}"><i>{Asker} asked:</i></div><br><span class="title">{Question}</span><hr color={color:title}>{Answer}
{block:IndexPage}<div class="textnote"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountwithLabel}</a></div>
<ul class="textbuttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
<li>{LikeButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
</ul><br>
{/block:IndexPage}
</div>
{/block:Answer}
 
{block:Video}
{block:IndexPage}
<center>
{Video-250}</center>
{block:IndexPage}<div class="textnote"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountwithLabel}</a></div>
<ul class="textbuttons">
<li>{ReblogButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
<li>{LikeButton color="gray" size=15}</li>
</ul><br>
{/block:IndexPage}
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
<center>
{Video-500}</center>
{/block:PermalinkPage}
{block:Video}
 
{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:HasTags} &middot; {block:Tags}<a href="TagURL"> #{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:hasTags}
{/block:PermalinkPage}
 
{block:PostNotes}
<div class="notess">{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{block:NoteCount}<br><span class="title">{NoteCountWithLabel}:</span>{/block:NoteCount}
<br>{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
</div>
 
{/block:Posts}
 
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Pagination}
<div id="pagination">
{block:NextPage}
<a id="nextPage" href="{NextPage}"></a>
{/block:NextPage}
{block:PreviousPage}
<a href="{PreviousPage}"></a>
{/block:PreviousPage}
</div>
{/block:Pagination}
{/block:IndexPage}
</div>

<!----- SCROLL TOP A2 ---->

<a id="scrlTop" href="#" style="position: fixed; top: 310px; right: 10px; ">BACK</br> TO TOP</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, can you actually share your blog? It's difficult to tell without an actual example. My guess is that it could be to do with the post type you are reblogging. If you change the css for the reblog, it could also affect your own unique posts, but it needs further investigation

Comment: OK, apologies, I thought that was the blog you were reblogging from. So the post you reblogged is an answer post, there it has a totally different structure to the photo posts. The issue is there is no way to identify a reblog in the markup (as far as I can tell) so you could write css to affect the layout, but it would apply to any post of the same type, including your own. To make one small improvement you could change this css `.answer img { max-width: 250px; height: auto; }` to this: `.answer img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`.

Comment: See image 1: https://i.imgur.com/Qpml18T.png and image 2: https://i.imgur.com/Mr2Wwhi.png but changing the css above might cause other issues (I think it will be OK, basically the theme uses masonry to calculate heights and then space the posts using absolute positioning, so you will need to test this first)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it doesn't eliminate the gray area around the picture ...

Comment: You can remove this line from the css: `.answer { background: #f0f0f0; }` you can do more styling than this, it depends how comfortable with css you are. Also if you can inspect element in chrome you can play around with the css properties to see how they would look.

Comment: The main question is, why is behaving like this apparently random (?) what trigger the `<div class="answer">` and his css style?

Comment: Because Tumblr has several different post types. Text, Photo, Photoset, Quote, Link, Audio, Video. They have to have different markup to accommodate the different content, you can potentially rationalise some of them and make them more uniform.